# Pivoting calculation Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have output below as

where *sum(minutes)* is used as aggregate of **comp_type** and **ram_type** group by

```
comp_type | ram_type | Minutes
    PC           4         50
    PC           6         65
    PC           8         100
    PC           16        160
    Mac          4         20
    Mac          6         45
    Mac          8         74
    Mac          16        88
```

How can I pivot this to where my output is below where the sum amounts are % of each comp_type total?

```
ram_type   PC   Mac
4         .13   .09
6         .17   .20
8         .27   .33
16        .43   .39
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select ram_type,
       max(case when comp_type = 'PC' then minutes end) / ram_type as pc,
       max(case when comp_type = 'Mac' then minutes end) / ram_type as mac
from t
group by ram_type;
```

EDIT:

I may have misunderstood the computation.  If you want the minutes as a proportion of total:

```
select ram_type,
       (sum(case when comp_type = 'PC' then minutes end) /
        sum(sum(case when comp_type = 'PC' then minutes end)) over ()
       ) as pc,
       (sum(case when comp_type = 'Mac' then minutes end) /
        sum(sum(case when comp_type = 'Mac' then minutes end)) over ()
       ) as mac
from t
group by ram_type;
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont get the / ram type in the answer ? I wanted the % of each ram_type out of their comp type as the output in my expected output above

Comment: also ram_type is a text column so wanted the minutes ( for that ram_type for that row) / total minutes for that comp_type as the %

Comment: @Chris90 . . . I misunderstood the calculation.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using some cool functions that looks quite elegant to my eyes utilises [RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOTai.png) and  [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html)

```
select * from 
  (
    select 
          ram_type  
        , comp_type 
        , ratio_to_report(minutes) over (partition by comp_type) ratio 
     from cte
  ) 
  pivot ( sum(ratio) for comp_type in ('PC','Mac') )
```

[image]

You can copy/paste/run straight into snowflake:

```
with cte as ( select     'PC' comp_type   ,        4  ram_type,         50 minutes
union select     'PC' comp_type   ,        6  ram_type,         65 minutes
union select     'PC' comp_type   ,        8  ram_type,         100 minutes
union select     'PC' comp_type   ,        16 ram_type,         160 minutes
union select     'Mac' comp_type   ,       4   ram_type,        20 minutes
union select     'Mac' comp_type   ,       6   ram_type,        45 minutes
union select     'Mac' comp_type   ,       8   ram_type,        74 minutes
union select     'Mac' comp_type   ,       16  ram_type,        88 minutes) 

select * from (select ram_type  , comp_type ,ratio_to_report(minutes) over (partition by comp_type) ratio from cte  ) pivot (sum(ratio) for comp_type in ('PC','Mac' ))
```

Comment: Nice usage of RATIO_TO_REPORT and Pivot